# Add custom Javascript to Prestashop

Tags: javascript, prestashop

After asking on the Prestashop forum and receiving no reply I wanted to ask you guys and hope for an answer.

I am trying to add an animated snow plugin to my shop but after looking at the header.tpl file which instructs you to not edit - how do I add my own Javascript to the head of my template?

I duplicated the default-theme and I am working from that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498995/how-to-add-custom-code-to-prestashop

Answer (score 6):

If the theme is `default-bootstrap`, then yes, you probably shouldn't modify it, if you intend to upgrade it (can be automatically upgraded using autoupgrade module).

Same can be true for 3rd party themes which are actively updated. But usually 3rd party themes don't get upgraded at all, which means you can modify theme templates. Because the templates are sort-of too complex to be extended by a child theme, it is ok to edit them directly. PretaShop doesn't have child-parent theme system. Just edit the templates directly.

If you would like your changes to be portable accross themes, then you should probably make a module. Inside the module use special functions to add `.js` and `.css` files to header:

```
mymodule.php

...

public function install()
{
   ...
   $this->registerHook('displayHeader');
   ...
}

public function hookDispayHeader()
{
   $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'js/script.js');
   $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/style.css');
}
```

If you need a quick way to add, just edit theme's `global.css` and `global.js`

You may also add the stysheet and script to autload folder:

`themes/theme1/css/autoload/` and 
`themes/theme1/js/autoload/`. Files inside these folder will be loaded for all pages.

Comment: Would this mean as I made a duplicate of "default-bootstrap" when they update the theme I will lose all of my work?

Comment: @D.Ashbridge No, because you "forked" the default theme and gave it a new name. It is now a new, separate theme.

Answer (score 2):

Add custom JS or CSS in theme, using this :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{$css_dir}bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="{$js_dir}bootstrap.js"></script>
```

$css_dir links to your theme css directory.
$js_dir links to your theme js directory.
Assuming you're working on your own theme (or duplicated the default-theme for custom use)

Comment: did this technique ever worked for you ? If i try to directly add the file to the js folder of the theme and call it with the  $js_dir i always get "the server responded with a status of 404 ".

Comment: Yep, this is a global variable used by Prestashop, it always works. Check file URL and name, sometimes path are wrong